# Adding JEST custom reporter causes compilation error: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, ts-jest, ts-node

I'm trying to add a custom reporter for jest and I succeeded to make it work, but when import some of the project files it fails with this error

> An error occurred while adding the reporter at path "...path/test-reporter/index.js".Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
> at Object. (...path/country.model.ts:21:43)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
> at Module.m._compile (...path/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@8.10.2_typescript@3.9.10/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:23)
> at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Object.require.extensions. [as .ts] (...path/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@8.10.2_typescript@3.9.10/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:861:12)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
> at Object. (...path)

Here is the different config files:

*test-reporter/index.js*

```
require('reflect-metadata');
const tsNode = require('ts-node');
const tsConfigPaths = require("tsconfig-paths");
const path = require('path');

const tsconfigPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json');
const tsconfig = require(tsconfigPath);

tsNode.register({
    compilerOptions: tsconfig.compilerOptions,
    transpileOnly: true,
});

tsConfigPaths.register({
    baseUrl: path.dirname(tsconfigPath),
    paths: tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths
});

module.exports = require('./test-reporter');
```

*test-reporter/test-reporter.ts*

```
import { Reporter, TestContext } from '@jest/reporters';
import { AggregatedResult } from '@jest/test-result';
import { Config } from '@jest/types';
import config from '../config/config';
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql';
import {
    FundMutationResolver,
    FundQueryResolver,
} from '@src/investorPortal/funds/resolvers/app/fund.resolver';
type CustomReporter = Pick<Reporter, 'onRunComplete'>;

interface Options {
    useReporter: boolean;
}

export default class TestReporter implements CustomReporter {
    constructor(private config: Config.InitialOptions, private options: Options) {}

    async onRunComplete(context: Set<TestContext>, results: AggregatedResult) {
        console.log('Your report is available!');

        const schema = await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [FundMutationResolver, FundQueryResolver],
            authChecker: () => true,
        }); <-- Issue is when I add those lines
    }
}
```

*jest.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
        },
    },
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    resetModules: true,
    globalSetup: '<rootDir>/e2e/config/globalSetup.ts',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/e2e/config/setupFile.ts'],
    reporters: ['default', '<rootDir>/e2e/test-reporter/index.js'],
    testMatch: ['**/e2e/**/*.test.ts'],
    rootDir: '.',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@config/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/config/$1',
        '^@common/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/common/$1',
        '^@seed/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/lib/seed/$1',
        '^@src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
        '^@services/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/services/$1',
        '^@lib/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/lib/$1',
        '^@tests-app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/__tests/app/$1',
        '^@tests-admin/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/__tests/admin/$1',
        '^package.json$': '<rootDir>/package.json',
    },
    testTimeout: 100000,
};
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "sourceRoot": "/",
        "target": "ES6",
        "outDir": ".build",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": ["es2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
        "rootDir": "./",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "paths": {
            "@config/*": ["config/*"],
            "@common/*": ["src/common/*"],
            "@seed/*": ["lib/seed/*"],
            "@src/*": ["src/*"],
            "@services/*": ["services/*"],
            "@lib/*": ["lib/*"],
            "@tests-app/*": ["__tests/app/*"],
            "@tests-admin/*": ["__tests/admin/*"]
        }
    },
   ...
}
```

I'm thinking the issue is related to relative paths, but no idea how to solve it.